# Camera portrait called by intent

Tags: android, android-camera, portrait

I use Android 2.3.
How can i set portrait mode in camera called by intent ?
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i set portrait mode in camera called by intent ?

You do not have control over that, because it is not your app.

The developer of the activity that is started via your `Intent` has complete freedom to implement their camera activity however they wish. Some will force an orientation (either landscape or portrait, though more often landscape), others will allow it to vary based on the way the user is holding the device. There is nothing in the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` protocol that allows you to request an orientation, and you cannot rely upon the other activity implementing that, anyway, even if it existed.